# How to serve static files using both express and ejs and send the data?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to serve files with express and send data to an html file using ejs. The problem is that I only have to use either express to serve the files or ejs to send data but for some reason I cant use both. My paths are right but probably I have to do something different to make both work. My code doesnt reach app.get when I use `app.use(express.static('../dist'))`, but when I comment that line it does send the data. If I can know what is happening that would be great.

My code is the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('../dist'));

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname, '../dist');

app.listen(4000, function() { console.log('listening')});

let views;

jwt.authorize((err, response) => {
    google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get(
        {
            auth: jwt,
            ids: 'ga:' + view_id,
            'start-date': '30daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'today',
            metrics: 'ga:sessions, ga:pageviews'
        },
        (err, result) => {
            console.log();
            views = result;
            console.log(views.data.rows[0][0]);

            app.get('/', function(req, res){
                console.log('test');
                res.render('../dist/index.html',{sessions:views.data.rows[0][0], pageviews:views.data.rows[0][1]});
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two routes match one URL, then whichever route is defined first will be used.

`/` hits the static route, finds a match (with an `index.html` file) and serves it up.

The route matching code never gets as far as `app.get('/'`.

---

EJS files are not static files. Don't mix them together with your static files.

If there isn't an `index.html` in the directory you keep your static files in, then it won't match on the static route, so the route matching code will reach `app.get('/'`.

You should probably separate the files (into `static` and `templates` rather then lumping them together in `dist`) and make it clear which files are EJS templates by giving them `.ejs` file extensions instead of `.html`.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by only using ejs files in my views folder (instead of using html) where I start my node server and using express for the rest of files (css, js, etc.). Before upvoting, I want to know if its possible to combine and serve an html file with express and use ejs with it? or should I use only ejs because I have to send variables from nodejs to my front end in this case?

Comment: That's the whole point of EJS! (Although it isn't limited to HTML). (If you aren't using EJS in a file, then running it through an EJS engine is inefficient and make it harder to set sensible cache-control headers).